Is asking about versions of Bohemian Rhapsody good on this site?
I am new to this site.
I want to ask the following question about versions of the rock music song Bohemian Rhapsody by Queen, but I am not sure whether it's appropriate for this site, for the reason that I see mainly classical music content here.
If it is not good for this site, it will also be very helpful if I could be informed about another site that might be appropriate for this question.
Question
In the live versions of Bohemian Rhapsody that I have listened to, the chorus 'prelude' part is excluded.  Are there any live versions that including the 'prelude'?

Firstly, while there are less questions about rock that classical music, both genres are just as on-topic for Music Practice & Theory.

A good place to check if your question is likely to be on-topic is the Help Centre.  The two most relevant pages are probably: What topics can I ask about here? and What types of questions should I avoid asking?
Looking at the first of these links, your question doesn’t fit particularly well into any of the general categories listed.  It seems like it’s more of a question from the perspective of a music fan, than a music performer/composer/theoretician.

There is, in fact, another related SE site that might be a better fit: Music Fans
Checking their Help Centre, it sounds to me like your question would fall into the “history of songs” category.  So perhaps, Music Fans would be a better fit.
I’ll defer a more definitive answer to one of our other moderators (Dom), because they happen to be a mod on both M:P&T and MF.

By checking the Stackexchange site list I think Music Fan is good for this.
